# Supremum and Infimum of sets and their maximums and minimums- solution check

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

1. $\{\frac {1}{1+x}: x>-1\}$
2. $\{x\in \Bbb R: \exists y\in \Bbb R\text{ with } (x+1)^2+5y^2<4\}$

For 1) $\inf(A)=0$ = no min

And supremum = 1 since $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac {1}{1+x})=1$ and no max

For 2) since $(x+1)^2$ will always give a positive result we should take $x=0$ as the infimum which is also the min. For supremum and max: If we take $x=2$ hen $(x+1)^2=4$ which would in this case be the supremum i guess? and max doesnt exisit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 the supremum is wrong ($\lim_{x\to\infty}1/(1+x)=0$, not $1$, but $\lim _{x\to -1}\ldots = \infty$).

For 2 note that we are *not* taking the extremal values of $(x+1)^2+5y^2$, but of the set of $x$ values. These can be negative. But as you have reasoned both $(x+1)^2$ and $y^2$ are non-negative. So
$$ (x+1)^2 + 5y^2 < 4 $$
if and only if
$$ (x+1)^2 < 4 $$
(you can always just choose $y=0$, but once $(x+1)^2\geq4$ not $y$ get this under $4$ again). This the case if and only if
$$ -2 < x+1 < 2 $$
From this you should be able to find sup and inf as well as whether they are max and min.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help...as for 1) sorry I made a mistake

Comment: Ouh no sorry for inf and min = -1 and sup would be 2 max doesn't exist

Comment: @What case are you referring to? In 1) the inf is $0$ and the sup is $\infty$ with no min, no max. In 2) the inf is $-2-1=-3$ and the sup is $2-1=1$ and no min, no max (as for these values $(x+1)^2=(\pm2)^2=4$).

Comment: hey i was referring to the second question. Yeah thanks i see now why your answer is correct, i wasnt thinking...Thank you

Comment: And btw for the first question,i thought about it again if x=1 then 1/2  would be greater than every other element in the set so shouldnt x=1? for the sup and max?

Comment: Look closely at how the sets are defined. The first set is defined as the set of the values of $1/(1+x)$, while the second set is defined by the arguments $x$. So in the first set if $x=1$ then the actual value in the set would be $1/2$. So if anything the max should be $1/2$. But your assumtion that $1/2$ was maximal is wrong. If you set $x=0$ then the corresponding value would be $1$. If you set $x=-1/2$ the corresponding value would be $2$. If you set $x=-1+1/k$ then the corresponding value would be $k$.